# Find value in the List(Of T)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, list

I'm new to List(Of T). Please help me.

I load my List value when system running. How to search for data that have in the List?

*1. My List class*

```
Public Class Directory
    Public strdirname As String
    Public strdircategory As String
    Public strdirlevel As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal m_dirname As String, ByVal m_dirlevel As String, ByVal m_dircat As String)
        Try
            strdirname = m_dirname
            strdirlevel = m_dirlevel
            strdircategory = m_dircat
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error new instance.Ex-" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Property ShopName() As String
        Get
            Return strdirname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            strdirname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ShopLevel() As String
        Get
            Return strdirlevel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            strdirlevel = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ShopCategory() As String
        Get
            Return strdircategory
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            strdircategory = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

*2. My new instance for List*

```
MyDir = New List(Of Directory)
```

In my search page, I want to find lets say a category eg: food & beverages. How to find all the data from the list where the `strdircategory = "Food & Beverages"`? Some page need to get by Level, Name also.

If I wanna search from the list, should I new the List again? Please advise.

## Edited:

```
Dim filterSpecific As List(Of Directory) = MyDir.FindAll(Function(p As Directory) p.strdircategory = txtkey.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

To *find* an element in your `List(Of T)`, use the [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method (for a single element):

> **List(Of T).Find Method**
>
> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire List.

or [`FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for all elements):

> **List(Of T).FindAll Method**
>
> Retrieves all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.

So, in your case, just use

```
Dim result = yourlist.FindAll(Function(d) d.strdircategory = "Food & Beverages")
```

You could also use the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method (which returns a lazy query instead of a new `List(Of T)`).

Comment: Hi @sloth, Please find my edited post. That is what I use. My total return data confirm more than 1. So I put it into another list. I dont wanna mess with the data that already exist in the list. But the filterSpecific count is 0. Mean, when I step onto it, "No children available"..

Comment: @Luiey Since you're comparing text, ensure that the strings are really  equal (case, trailing/leading whitespace etc.).